# What is the meaning of the following code snippet and how is it working? Also, is there any alternative to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
    print(f'__get__(instance={instance}, owner={owner})')
    return instance.__dict__.get(self.name)
```

I am learning descriptors and quite new to it so I can't wrap my head around the following code `instance.__dict__.get(self.name)` and what is the significance of it and if there is another alternative to it.

Answer (score 0):

__get__ implements Python's property type.

E.g. If you have a class called "Foo" that has a property called "bar" then your function is the implementation of calling Foo.bar

In your example, calling the __get__ function will return the names of the instances of Foo in Python's namespace. In other words it will print out the names of objects of class Foo.